# UITableView won't present

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a very strange situation in my app and i can't explain or locate the bug.
I have a UIViewController with a tableView in it.
In the table view I have 3 prototype cells, also i have 2 section that are divided like so:

first section: row 0 (cell ID: episodeScrollersCell)
second section: row 0 (cell ID: addCommentsCell)
              : row 1+ (cell ID: commentCell)

The required methods in the protocol are listed below.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger rowNum;
    if(section == 0){
        rowNum = 1;
    }else{
        rowNum = 1; // here is the problem. If i change the number of row to above 1
    }
    return rowNum;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier;
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cellIdentifier = episodeScrollersCell;
    }else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0){
        cellIdentifier = addCommentsCell;
    }else{
        cellIdentifier = commentCell;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    return cell;
}
```

Now the problem arises when I want to have 2 rows or above in the second section (i.e to have 2 prototype cells in one section), the view Controller won't show. I've logged the cellForRowAtIndexPath: method to see if the cells gets loaded and they do.

Any advice?
Thanks,

Comment: Please elaborate "the viewcontroller dont show.." What happens exactly

Comment: When a UITableView does not show, put a breakpoint in numberOfRowsInSection. If it is not hit then 99 times out of 100 you have forgotten to hook up the datasource and delegate of the table view.

Comment: the Delegate and the DataSource are hooked up.

Comment: And by "wont show" I mean that that when I segue to the view Controller with the table View in it, it seems like the segue doesn't work. The current view Controller (the one that I'm seguing from) stays visible

Comment: Log your cell object after and make sure it isn't `nil`.

Comment: I guess the issue is that you don't create cell object.

Comment: k, I found the problem. I have a method that return the height of each prototype cell, and for the third one it keeps returning 0 for the height.

Comment: But i had no clue that this will cause my table view to un-appear. Well any way thanks all of you for your time and effort

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be doing is trying to dequeue a reusable cell with a chance that no cell has been created before. However, if no cells have been created/allocated, then the dequeue will return a `nil` value. This tells the program that for the given `indexPath` there is NO cell to be displayed.

So, if you get a nil value from the dequeue function, your table will try to create a new cell with the given cell identifier. So, I would suggest you do something like the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier;
    if(indexPath.section == 0){
        cellIdentifier = episodeScrollersCell;
    }else if (indexPath.section == 1 && indexPath.row == 0){
        cellIdentifier = addCommentsCell;
    }else{
        cellIdentifier = commentCell;
    }
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(!cell){
        if(indexPath.section == 0){
            //Initialise a new cell here, through a NIB or code
            //For eg. cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: ...];
        }
        //Do the specific initialisation for each type of cell you need here
    }
    return cell;
}
```

This way, when the dequeue function returns a `NIL` value, your program automatically creates a new cell to fit in that place.

Hope this helps.